# Refresh named ranges when #NAME? in a worksheet that's being updated

Tags: excel, named-ranges, vba

I am finishing an .xls that is meant to update another .xls (a tool) by a macro. So basically the idea is to click in a button, choose your target file (the one you will update) and then the macro will patch the file with some modifications made by copying, pasting and replacing formulas and adding sheets. This patch/update file only includes the cells and sheets that will be added into the target file.

I started to get some troubles when I included there formulas that refer to named ranges that only exist in the tool (target file) but they don't exist in the patch .xls. As there are many names I decided to break all the connections in the patch file so the formulas are copied to the target file without internal references. I wanted to avoid the issue that those references get stuck to inappropriate and old files.

These intentional link corruptions made the patch file to show the formulas that use named ranges the error "#NAME?". I don't care that this happens there but I do when this error remains after copying those formulas, in the target file. In the target file those names exist.

I included this line to refresh calculations but didn't work (the equivalent to Alt-Ctrl-Shift + F9)

```
wbTarget.Application.CalculateFullRebuild
```

As you will be able to see in A3:A6 I made them work by manually pressing F2 (to edit) and intro. This action restore the connection with the name declared. This is obviously not a solution to make all cells work properly.

Print screen
It's just an example but this happens in some other sheets. #¿NOMBRE? means #NAME?

[image]

Comment: Can you give us the definition of `cF2FAgency4` ?

Comment: what happens if you try `wbTarget.Save` and make sure calculate before save is turned on? I have noticed that `Calculate` method doesn't necessarily work well when you have formula heavy workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the code below to reenter formulas for the whole sheet:

```
Sub ReEnterFormulas()
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        Cell.Formula = Mid(Cell.Formula, 2)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't get any alarm of your answer but thanks anyway. I don't know if it worked I just made a macro that replaces the "=" for "*=" and then again with "=". It's not as efficient as I wanted but works fine.

Comment: @Gerónimo if it helps to solve the issue, please click to accept the answer.